# Fetch Backbone.Collection by JSON object

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

in `jQuery` we can supply json when perform `GET` operation. But I don't see any options in backbone to supply object like backbone.collection.create or update

```
collection.fetch({
    data: {
        ip_id: this.column
    },
    success: this.constructing
});
```

this is what can I think of right now

Comment: The snippet you provided does what you want, as far as I can tell http://jsfiddle.net/Z8ca8/

Comment: this.column is an object which whenever fetch is triggered, it will be appended to url. It shouldnt be that way.

Answer (score 0):

Since `this.column` is a json object, you need to stringify it. Try this

```
collection.fetch({
    data: {
        ip_id: JSON.stringify(this.column)
    },
    success: this.constructing
});
```

Comment: is there any other way rather than stringify it?

Comment: @MuhaiminAbdul This is the right way to do it. What is the problem that you are trying to solve ?

Comment: i have a long list of array. And i dont think append it to `url` just feel not the right way

Comment: Why do you want to send it at the time of fetch ? A GET request can only send data in the URL parameters. You can also use POST while using fetch method given your server allows it.